# Xcode changing a button background image for various devices

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

How can I change button background image - I need one for all iPhones and another (due to size) for iPads. I have square buttons imitating keyboard with smaller background image. On iPad font on buttons is twice bigger, but they are not squares anymore. So I made bigger backgroud image to make them squares again, but how can I change that image only for iPads in storyboard. Is it possible?
Thanks.

on iPhones:
[image]

on Ipads:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can design the layout using size class. The size class for iPad is R*R.

Comment: for button background image I can`t choose size class like for font.

Comment: Add image as a child of button, now you can use size class as image property of UIImage provide size class.